# Shell scripting basic format?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm brand new to shell scripting and I've looked up some tutorials about basic shell scripting, but my script still is not running. I'm not totally sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to crack a CTF for some context. The error I'm getting is "line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `done'"

Does anyone have any tips on how to fix this or any resources that could point me in the correct direction?

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while :
do
   if [[ "$(md5sum < (echo -n "${i}d470d406"))" =~ "0badbeef" ]] ; then 
       echo $i
       break
   let i+=1
done
```

I tried to run this script and am getting the error stated above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to close the `if` with `fi`.

Paste your script on https://www.shellcheck.net/